# Content Editable on <content> insertion point

Tags: html, polymer, contenteditable, shadow-dom

I'm looking to create a custom element that's Shadow DOM wraps `contenteditable` content, without it itself being assigned `contenteditable`.

My first attempts have been:

```
<template>
  <div contenteditable="true">
   <content></content>
  </div>
</template>
```

and this slightly less hopeful attempt:

```
<template>
  <div>
   <content contenteditable="true"></content>
  </div>
</template>
```

But no success on either. Is this even possible? I haven't had a problem making `contenteditable` elements inside Shadow DOM, but the aim is to have that content reflected in the Light DOM as well.

One last note, I've been doing all my testing inside Polymer, I don't think it changes anything as it's using native Shadow DOM in Chrome, but perhaps that's having an effect.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's possible. You'll just have to get the reference of the light dom child inside your `ready` or `attached` callback and set its `contentEditable` property to true.

Here's an example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <base href="http://polygit.org/polymer+:master/components/">
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
</head>

<body>
  <dom-module id="my-element">
    <template>
      <style>
        :host {
          display: block;
          height: 100px;
          background-color: #cacaca;
        }
      </style>
      <content id="insertionPoint" select="*"></content>
    </template>
  </dom-module>

  <my-element>
    <div></div>
  </my-element>
  <script>
    (function() {
      Polymer({
        is: 'my-element',
        ready: function() {
          var el = Polymer.dom(this.$.insertionPoint).getDistributedNodes()[0];
          el.contentEditable = true;
          el.style.height = "100%";
        }
      });
    })();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! But this doesn't quite solve my problem, it means that I couldn't have plain text nodes that I could edit, e.g. `<my-element>foo bar</my-element>`, which is a very large use case for me.

Comment: @Bede Text nodes are not content-editable. If that's your case then make the custom element be the one that's content-editable.

Comment: @Bede It's that simple.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid setting contenteditable directly on the host. This is because I want this to work in both Shadow DOM and Polymer's Shady DOM, when it's set on Shady DOM, the contenteditable means that even the Shady elements can be manipulated